# SignalR - Passing on a custom exception type in the OnIncomingError method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

We currently have a module setup in SignalR for passing on our exception messages to the client, however, we would like to pass on the exception source as well.

```
public class HubErrorMessageModule : HubPipelineModule
{
    protected override void OnIncomingError(ExceptionContext exceptionContext,
                                            IHubIncomingInvokerContext invokerContext)
    {
        dynamic caller = invokerContext.Hub.Clients.Caller;
        caller.ExceptionHandler(exceptionContext.Error.Message);
    }
}
```

When a custom exception is thrown, our JQuery promise fail handler receives an object with `source: "Exception"`. If we throw a `HubException`, the JQuery promise object receives `source: "HubException"`.

To avoid catch/throwing our custom exception classes as `HubException`, is there a way to return the exception type as the `source` string for the JQuery promise?